# Spike lighting Toon Shader

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, npr

I'm trying to get this kind of style in evvee with dynamic lighting:

[image]

By displacing a simple toon shader i got this result :

[image]

however since the displacement is only on the x-y axis it doesn't work if lights are anywhere else :

[image]

To make this work, it would be great to have a vector representing gradient direction in the shader nodes to then use it for displacement.

Do you have any ideas/leads on how to achieve this ?

My shader nodes :
[image]

Thanks in advance

The file : [image]

Comment: can u provide a blend file so we don't have to rebuild it manually? thx.

Comment: Here it is sorry